# reading Html file through OLEDB fails

Tags: c#, winforms, oledbdatareader

i am trying to read html file through OLEDB reader using following code

```
DataTable dTable;
string strDataSource = "";
string strDBFile = "";
long intPos = 0;
strDataSource = mstrFilePath;
dTable = new DataTable();
mCon = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection();
mCon.ConnectionString  = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + openFileDialog1.FileName + ";Extended Properties=\"HTML Import;HDR=NO;IMEX=1\";");     
if (mCon.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    mCon.Open(); // gettting failed here
}
dTable = mCon.GetSchema("Tables");
        bSelectionChanged = true;
        lstTables.Items.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow DRow in dTable.Rows)
        {

            if (DRow["TABLE_TYPE"].ToString() == "TABLE" || DRow["TABLE_TYPE"].ToString() == "VIEW")
            {
                intPos = DRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().LastIndexOf("FilterDatabase");
                lstTables.Items.Add(DRow["TABLE_NAME"]);
            }
        }
        if (lstTables.Items.Count == 1)
        {
            lstTables.Visible = false;
            grdSampleDataControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        }
        else
        {
            lstTables.Visible = true;
            grdSampleDataControl.Dock = DockStyle.None;
        }
        bSelectionChanged = true;
        dTable.Dispose();
        mCon.Close();
        openFileDialog1.Dispose();
```

It is getting failed here wiht exception\

> The Microsoft Office Access database engine cannot open or write to the file ''. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.

But file is not opened anywhere ??

**Edit**

On debug, When it throws exception at `mCon.Open()`, If i press F10 compiler moves to next statement and run the programm succesfully. why it is so ??

Comment: could it be the `openFileDialog1` that maybe needs to be disposed?

Comment: @FurkanEkinci i am not opening it anywhere using `openFileDialog1`.. I am using  `openFileDialog1` to just read file name. File is not opened anywhere

Comment: Are you sure access closed too, not file?

Comment: @FurkanEkinci access means what ?? Are you talking about Connection !!!

Comment: OK. Can you tell what is access file path?

Comment: @FurkanEkinci File Path is `D:\Projects\CDR_RAW_FILES\8435921487.htm`

Comment: @RajeevKumar I mean MS Access. Sometimes people close all windows in MS Access and guess closed access file.

Comment: Can you try to use hard code path? Use **D:\Projects\CDR_RAW_FILES\8435921487.htm** instead of **openFileDialog1.FileName**

Comment: @FurkanEkinci Does it make any sense ??

Comment: openFileDialog may be causing the error like @JensKloster said.

Comment: I'm trying to get same error, so what kind data your html file store?

Comment: @FurkanEkinci Is there any option of attaching file in stackoverflow. So i can attach sample html

Comment: @RajeevKumar I found a sample data from [here](http://ewbi.blogs.com/develops/2006/12/reading_html_ta.html) and tried to open connection. It worked correctly. Does you data format look like in link?

Comment: @RajeevKumar you can share here (in question) an instance of your data format.

Comment: @FurkanEkinci Just like that. But in my case, Why compiler on pressing F10 Ignore that exception ??

Comment: @FurkanEkinci try to reopen some other file or same file multiple times ..

Comment: @FurkanEkinci I have added some more code. have a look at edited question

Comment: Actually if you get error in **mCon.Open();** line, I think below codes are not important for now.

Comment: @FurkanEkinci It is not failing in first 2-3 times actually. But if i keep on doing it for some other files it fails randomly for any file.

Comment: [Here](http://screencast.com/t/BDQ5Nx5Amq) is my screencast.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your Acccess Database file is open.

You can not keep file open, and do changes on that file dynamically.

While the program using that file is running, it tries to open that file.

But, if file is already open exclusively by user, then it fails.

Close the file, and then try to open the connection.

For other details on it, follow this [DISCUSSION](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/3479cc5a-2bca-4e9c-9fdb-ec3f96065a52).

Comment: But i am not openning any access database here. I am just reading HTML file ?? may be i am not getting you